# Server (all services) unresponsive over IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6, ubuntu-18.04

I've just deployed a new server running Ubuntu 18.04, however, it isn't responding to any service over IPv6. It should be supporting SSH and Nginx over IPv6, but both connections timeout. I've double checked the `AAAA` entries exist and are valid and correct on the DNS side. I've also checked the server is setup to listen for IPv6 for both SSH and Nginx and there shouldn't be anything blocking it. But I'm at a loss at what could be the culprit.

The server connects over IPv4 fine, and it's not a local to the device trying to connect as various devices on different networks, as well as a few IPv6 connectivity testing sites all report no connectivity on IPv6.

EDIT: Server should be accessible through `mystral.xyz` (will just show Nginx welcome/default screen) and `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::/64`

**netstat -tlnp**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19582/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27152/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6532/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19582/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      555/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1135/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6532/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      19582/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19582/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1135/sshd
```

**ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**ip6tables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-before-logging-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-before-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-after-logging-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-reject-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            
ufw6-track-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dhcpv6-client
ufw6-skip-to-policy-input  udp      anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:dhcpv6-server

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ufw6-user-forward  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ufw6-logging-deny  all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 130
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 131
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 132
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 143
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 144
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 145
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 146
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 147
ACCEPT     udp      fe80::/10            fe80::/10            udp spt:dhcpv6-server dpt:dhcpv6-client
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             ff02::fb             udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             ff02::f              udp dpt:1900
ufw6-user-input  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             rt type:0
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp packet-too-big
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp neighbour-solicitation HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmp router-advertisement HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 141 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 142 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 130
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 131
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 132
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 143
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 148 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    anywhere             anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 149 HL match HL == 255
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 151 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 152 HL match HL == 1
ACCEPT     ipv6-icmp    fe80::/10            anywhere             ipv6-icmptype 153 HL match HL == 1
ufw6-user-output  all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw6-logging-deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-input (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw6-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain ufw6-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all      anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all      anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain ufw6-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw6-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw6-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**ip -6 a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a01:4f9:c010:5335::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9400:ff:fe37:30e0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the name and address of this host? We can try accessing it from different paths on the Internet. Firewall is not the only thing that can prevent connections.

Comment: @JohnMahowald – mystral.xyz (should just show a Nginx welcome/default screen) and the IPv6 is 2a01:4f9:c010:5335::/64

Comment: For `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::` I have routes to hetzner but connection timed out.  If this IP address is on a host interface, prove it by showing them with `ip -6 a`

Comment: @JohnMahowald I've added the output show the address bound to eht0 with global scope

Comment: The address on the interface is `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::1/64`, not `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::/64`. Did you incorrectly configure the DNS for the network, but not the host?

Comment: @RonMaupin Your right, I missed that. It looks like it might be a bug on Hetzner's Cloud Console as it lists the IPv6 address for the server as ´2a01:4f9:c010:5335::/64´ and that's what I copied when configuring the DNS while the server was initially booting/installing OS. Amending the DNS record's to add the 1 has fixed the issue. If you post as an answer I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @Flatlyn Probably your server has the whole /64 assigned? That's not so rare for IPv6 servers. You could then use address(es) from that subnet as you like (e.g. running different sites on different addresses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address on the interface is `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::1/64`, not `2a01:4f9:c010:5335::/64`. You incorrectly configured the DNS for the network, but not the host.

Per your comment, changing DNS to the host fixed the problem.